# unnecessary characters in Insert Into

Tags: php, mysql

I try to Insert Into to table some values but i have a problem. there are unnecessary characters (\n) in the fields key1,key2,key3,key4. Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO questions (`key1`,`key2`, `key3`, `key4`, `user_id`, `creation_date`, `taksi`, `type`, `permission`)
        VALUES ('\n17','\n18','\n19','\n20','5','2012-12-18 14:37:31', '1', 'multiple_choice', '0')
```

how can I avoid \n  ?

original code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

      $key1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key1']);
      $key2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key2']);
      $key3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key3']);
      $key4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key4']);

      $taksi = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['taksi']);
      $permission = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['permission']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (`key1`,`key2`, `key3`, `key4`, `user_id`, `creation_date`, `taksi`, `type`, `permission`)
        VALUES ('".$key1."','".$key2."','".$key3."','".$key4."','".$user_id."','".$today."', '".$taksi."', '".$type."', '".$permission."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: How about replacing them with nothing?

Comment: Why do you have them in the first place? Line breaks don't just "show up" or something. They came from somewhere.

Comment: from where, you are getting value of this variable ? `textbox or textarea`

Comment: try using `trim()` on the values, it should remove all whitespaces from the end and the beginning of the strings...

Comment: Do you need `VALUES ('17','18','19',...)` instead of `VALUES ('\n17','\n18','\n19',...)`? If so, you can `trim()` the values before putting them into query. But  `trim()` is not enough, actually, you have to validate the data before putting it into a query anyway. If it's a number, use `intval()` or `PDO::PARAM_INT` when using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: i show you the original code

Comment: i change insert into like this:  $sql = "INSERT INTO questions (key1,key2, key3, key4, user_id, creation_date, taksi, type, permission) VALUES (nl2br('\n$key1'),nl2br('\n$key2'),nl2br('\n$key3'),nl2br('\n$key4'),'".$user_id‌​."','".$today."', '".$taksi."', '".$type."', '".$permission."')"; but is wrong

Comment: this is the solution: $clean1 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key1);
      $clean2 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key2);
      $clean3 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key3);
      $clean4 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key4); thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `str_replace`. Create your query as a String variable, and then replace all instances of `\n` with nothingness.

Comment: this is the solution: $clean1 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key1);
      $clean2 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key2);
      $clean3 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key3);
      $clean4 = str_replace('\n', "\n", $key4); thanks a lot my friend!!

Comment: Not a problem.If i helped be sure to mark an accepted solution. Also, feel free to edit comments to include specifics so that it may in the future help others. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like that hope it will work --

```
VALUES (nl2br('\n17'), nl2br('\n18'), nl2br('\n19'), nl2br('\n20') .....
```

Comment: i change it like this: $sql = "INSERT INTO questions (`key1`,`key2`, `key3`, `key4`, `user_id`, `creation_date`, `taksi`, `type`, `permission`)
  VALUES (nl2br('\n$key1'),nl2br('\n$key2'),nl2br('\n$key3'),nl2br('\n$key4'),'".$user_id."','".$today."', '".$taksi."', '".$type."', '".$permission."')"; but is wrong. What  I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to assign these **nl2br('\n17')** .. to different variables. Then place those variable into the query.

Comment: $key1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key1']);
      $key2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key2']);
      $key3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key3']);
      $key4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key4']);
      $clean1 = nl2br("\n$key1");
      $clean2 = nl2br("\n$key2");
      $clean3 = nl2br("\n$key3");
      $clean4 = nl2br("\n$key4"); the outcome is: INSERT INTO questions (`key1`,`key2`, `key3`, `key4`, `user_id`, `creation_date`, `taksi`, `type`, `permission`)
  VALUES ('<br />
22','<br />
\n27','<br />
\n28','<br />
\n29','5','2012-12-18 15:58:12', '1', 'multiple_choice', '0')

Comment: It will be that. if you don't want '<br /> 22' then remove '\n' from your query statement.

Comment: this is my problem, how remove \n!

Comment: my query is $sql = "INSERT INTO questions (`key1`,`key2`, `key3`, `key4`, `user_id`, `creation_date`, `taksi`, `type`, `permission`)
  VALUES ('".$clean1."','".$clean2."','".$clean3."','".$clean4."','".$user_id."','".$today."', '".$taksi."', '".$type."', '".$permission."')";
  mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

Try to encodeURIComponent before sending those keys thru $_GET.